# Where does the redirect from ViewPost.aspx to Post.aspx happen?

Tags: 2013, my-site, blog, redirect

When a user wants to open a blog post, he clicks on a link like:

`http://mysitehost/my/[USERNAME]/Blog/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=2`

SharePoint now redirects the user to

```
http://mysitehost/my/[USERNAME]/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=[LISTGUID]&ID=2&Web=[WEBGUID]
```

In which file does this redirect from `ViewPost.aspx` to `Post.aspx` happen? I don't see any code-behind files behind `ViewPost.aspx` nor a specific webpart.